When ATC tells you to climb or descent now, do the speed restrictions on SIDs and STARs still apply? (EASA)

I am flying the ELSUP 1H departure. After taking off, I get told to climb to FL100. Do I have to comply with the speed restrictions? Is it the same for a STAR?

According to Canadian rules, Yes. I will do more research and try to make my answer more relevant to this particular question but as of now what follows is based on Canadian CARs.
Unless specifically stated in the clearance, the balance of the SID remains unchanged despite ATC revision of a component.
According the the Transport Canada AIM (eff. 0901z March 21, 2024 - 0901z October 3, 2024):

A SID termination fix may be a NAVAID, intersection, or DME and is normally located on an established airway where the SID terminates and the en route phase of flight commences. The SID, as published, contains an altitude to climb to after departure; however, ATC may assign an altitude different from the altitude specified in the SID, provided the altitude is stated and a readback is obtained from the pilot prior to departure. In addition, where vector SIDs are used, ATC may assign a different initial departure heading. However, an ATC revision to any item of a SID does not cancel the SID.

The same applies for a STAR. Not only does amending one component not affect others but the pilot is also expected to re-intercept the STAR profile when given a partial deviation from the charted route.
From TC AIM Section 9.2.3.15 “Amending Routes”:

ATC may amend STAR routes by clearing the aircraft direct to a waypoint depicted within the STAR. ATC will confirm what to expect if they intend for the aircraft to rejoin the STAR procedure when initiating vectors. When an aircraft is cleared direct to a STAR/approach interface waypoint, unless it is cleared for an approach, the pilot shall proceed direct to the STAR waypoint, and not to the approach waypoint, to re-intercept the STAR profile.

Note: an ATC revision to a charted restriction supersedes all of the other charted restrictions of the same kind, eg. an ALT revision supersedes all other charted ALT restrictions, speed for speed and so on.
The STAR is cancelled either explicitly by ATC along with vectors/WPTs to follow thereon or when an approach clearance is issued.

References:
SID - TC AIM
IFR - Arrival Procedures - TC AIM

Your answer may well be correct, but it's hard to tell since you are referring to Canadian rules despite the question being about EASA.

@60levelchange Question didn’t mention EASA when I answered, although I guess I could’ve taken a closer look to where it says “EPPO” :-P

The answer is yes in both cases. ICAO PANS-ATM (Doc 4444) is mentioning:

4.6.4 SID and STAR
The flight crew shall comply with published SID and STAR speed restrictions unless the restrictions are explicitly cancelled or amended by the controller.

The phraseology for cancelling the restriction is also described in PANS-ATM. For SIDs:

6.3.2.4.1 Clearances to aircraft on a SID with remaining published level and/or speed restrictions shall indicate if such restrictions are to be followed or are cancelled. The following phraseologies shall be used with the following meanings:
[...]
d) CLIMB VIA SID TO (level), CANCEL SPEED RESTRICTION(S):
[...]
e) CLIMB VIA SID TO (level), CANCEL SPEED RESTRICTION(S) AT (point(s)):
[...]

Likewise for a STAR

6.5.2.4.1 Clearances to aircraft on a STAR with remaining published, level and/or speed restrictions shall indicate if such restrictions are to be followed or are cancelled. The following phraseologies shall be used with the following meaning:
[...]
d) DESCEND VIA STAR TO (level), CANCEL SPEED RESTRICTION(S):
[...]
e) DESCEND VIA STAR TO (level), CANCEL SPEED RESTRICTION(S) AT (point(s)):
[...]

d) is to cancel all speed restrictions of a SID/STAR. e) will be issued in order to cancel speed restriction at specific points.
You mentioned EASA. EASA has not incorporated this specific phraseology into SERA yet, although while researching for this answer, I found an amendment proposal to incorporate it to a future release.
EASA regulations take precedence over ICAO regulations; they don't completely replace them. If there is no reference to a subject in EASA SERA, then ICAO regulations are in force for that subject.
